# Profile data (x z) from a 3-D polyline for ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

I have a task to extract a profile data (x and z) for numerous segments of a 3-D polyline. I can do this using 3-d analyst (using 3d profile graph and export the data) for each segment of the polyline. However, this process is cumbersome as there are numerous segments of the polyline and each time the segment has to be selected and the process repeated for export.

Is there any python script for ArcMap that can automate the process by identifying the segments of the polyline and exporting the x-z values for each segment?

Comment: Can you amend you question to explain what you mean by X and Z? Is that X value the real world coordinate (so what about Y) or is a percentage along the line segment. A polyline is made up of many segment lines so this X is it the X of the start, centroid or end?

Comment: x = distance along the transect; z = elevation.

Comment: Sounds like you want to be using the [Interpolate Shape](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/interpolate-shape.htm) tool to pass the elevation data though to the vertices? As you have been talking about line segments then there are only two vertices the start and the end.

Comment: Split line at vertices and interpolate it as @Hornbydd suggested, follow the workflow below to get individual sections

Answer (score 2):

Input:

[image]

Workflow:

```
arcpy.FeatureVerticesToPoints_management("3dlines", "D:/Scratch/points.shp", "ALL")
arcpy.AddField_management("points", “Chainage", "DOUBLE")
```

Run this field calculator expression on field CHAINAGE:

```
def Chainage(id,shp):
 mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
 lr=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"3dlines")[0]
 q='"UNIQID"='+"'"+id+"'"
 with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lr, 'Shape@',q) as cursor:
  for row in cursor:  geom=row[0]
 L=geom.measureOnLine (shp.firstPoint)
 return L
#--------------------------------
Chainage( !UNIQID! , !Shape! )
```

It will work on shapefiles only, see definition query in above

```
arcpy.AddZInformation_3d("points", "Z")
```

Output:

[image]

You can bring it in Excel and view individual sections by using filter on UNIQID field

Comment: Thanks FelixIP! I think I am close to there. However, I could not get the field calculator going. It shows an error Error000539:Error running expression

Comment: Details of the error:                                                                      Error000539:Error running expression: def Chainage(id,shp): Chainage("L1",GPVARIANTOBJECT0)<type'exceptions.SyntaxError'>Invalid syntax (<string>,line1)

Comment: It is never easy to copy paste things into field calculator. Make sure indentations are correct. Also Chainage(!idname!,!Shape!)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to replicate the functionality of the 3D Analyst toolbar, which allows you to extract elevation data from a cross-section transect. If that's what you're looking for, I recently solved it with `StackProfile_3d`:

```
patch = r'F:\Joe_School\Thesis\data\grid_extract\mask400_1'
out_prof = r'F:\Joe_School\Thesis\scripts\Jerry\scratch.gdb\testprof'

import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
import arcpy.ddd as DDD

#env.overwriteOutput = True
env.outputCoordinateSystem = arcpy.Describe(patch).spatialReference
env.workspace = os.path.dirname(out_prof)

#Extract profile, save graph & table
arcpy.CheckOutExtension('3D')
tablename = 'prof_table'
graphname = 'prof_graph'
prof = DDD.StackProfile(out_prof, patch, tablename, graphname)
DM.SaveGraph(graphname, graphname + '.bmp')
arcpy.CheckInExtension('3D')
```

You can then take the data from `tablename` wherever you need it: numpy, a spreadsheet, etc. Here's what you get:
[image: Screenshot of table]

Possible duplicate of my [similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180867/replicate-elevation-profile-extraction-3d-analyst-toolbar-in-arcpy).